# Create Macro for redusing the size of the selected image on the spreadhseet by 50% and drawing a 0.25pt line around it

Tags: image, excel, format, edit, vba

I am writing a report detailing the sequence of a lot of graphs in Excel. I need to reduce the size of the image by 50% and draw a line of weight 0.25pt around it.

I have attempted to record a macro however this comes up blank. I have read that the picture formatting steps are not recorded and are ignored.

Im using Excel 2007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub EditShapes()
'This Sub Edit all Shapes in all Sheets

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each shp In sht.Shapes
            shp.Width = shp.Width / 2
            shp.Height = shp.Height / 2
            shp.Line.Weight = 0.25
        Next shp
Next sht

End Sub
```

To selected Shape

```
Sub EditSelectShape()
Dim shp As ShapeRange

Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange

shp.Width = shp.Width / 2
shp.Height = shp.Height / 2
shp.Line.Weight = 0.25

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, however rather than this being implemented for all pictures on all sheets, i would like it to be for a selected picture on the actual sheet not all - i will play around with your code to see what i can get. Thank you so much.